# Style table of contents from one two two columns when exeeding height

Tags: html, css

I am following this guide for styling my table of contents:
https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/simple-table-of-contents-toc-using-pure-html-and-css-code-9217

I have implemented it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/qr3m3a9e/

```css
#toc_container {
  background: #f9f9f9 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  display: table;
  font-size: 95%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 20px;
  width: auto;
}

.toc_title {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

#toc_container li, #toc_container ul, #toc_container ul li{
  list-style: outside none none !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="toc_container">
  <p class="toc_title">Contents</p>
  <ul class="toc_list">
    <li><a href="#First_Point_Header">1 First Point Header</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_1">1.1 First Sub Point 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_2">1.2 First Sub Point 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Second_Point_Header">2 Second Point Header</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Third_Point_Header">3 Third Point Header</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to know how I can change the `#toc_container` so that it has a fixed height and automatic width.

I tried changing the width from "auto" to "100%" and setting a height to "400px" but it's not wrapping the list into two columns as I would expect.

Comment: Just a quick note that you have an extra quote mark in your `ul` on line 3, which is why most of your code is red. Fix that, then you'll see only a few tags highlighted that also need fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `column-count`?

https://jsfiddle.net/qr3m3a9e/1/

```css
#toc_container {
    background: #f9f9f9 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    column-count: 2;
    font-size: 95%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: 400px;
}

.toc_title {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

#toc_container li, #toc_container ul, #toc_container ul li{
    list-style: outside none none !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="toc_container">
    <p class="toc_title">Contents</p>
    <ul class="toc_list">
        <li><a href="#First_Point_Header">1 First Point Header</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_1">1.1 First Sub Point 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_2">1.2 First Sub Point 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Second_Point_Header">2 Second Point Header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Third_Point_Header">3 Third Point Header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_1">1.1 First Sub Point 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_2">1.2 First Sub Point 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Second_Point_Header">2 Second Point Header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Third_Point_Header">3 Third Point Header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_1">1.1 First Sub Point 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_2">1.2 First Sub Point 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Second_Point_Header">2 Second Point Header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Third_Point_Header">3 Third Point Header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_1">1.1 First Sub Point 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_2">1.2 First Sub Point 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Second_Point_Header">2 Second Point Header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Third_Point_Header">3 Third Point Header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_1">1.1 First Sub Point 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_2">1.2 First Sub Point 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Second_Point_Header">2 Second Point Header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Third_Point_Header">3 Third Point Header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_1">1.1 First Sub Point 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_2">1.2 First Sub Point 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Second_Point_Header">2 Second Point Header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Third_Point_Header">3 Third Point Header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_1">1.1 First Sub Point 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_2">1.2 First Sub Point 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Second_Point_Header">2 Second Point Header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Third_Point_Header">3 Third Point Header</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well in the jsfiddle but not on my automatically generated list for some reason. I am using jquery (http://ndabas.github.io/toc/).  It looks as if the page loads it in two columns at first but quickly changes back to one.